# AngularJs - How can I use a datepicker in magic search?

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to integrate [Magic Search](https://github.com/eucalyptus/magic-search) in my angular 1.5x project. I want to give an option to select a date. I couldn't find anything related to this in their docs.

Can someone guide me in the right direction ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Magic search is a text based filter. There's no mention of using datepicker element in magic search, so this might not be possible.